# cant write file to hard disk in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi I checked All Questions Present here did not helped me so I asked

Ok here we go

I try to copy file from "Resources" to "C:\Test" Folder does not work for me

here what i tried:

Firstly, I put test.txt file in my resources to copy to "C:\Test" folder but I get an error

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Test", My.Resources.Test)
   End Sub
End Class
```

i get error i cant even debug

**ERROR** :- *Error 1   Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'*.

So is there any way I can copy .txt file to "C:\Test" folder if it exist so that I can copy replace it ?

Now I changed the extension of test.txt to test.bin

It allows me to start the program in debug and no error with this code;

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Test", My.Resources.Test)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now when i click button1 i get error

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Test' is denied.
```

So i want to copy the file and replace if it is present there suppose file is test.txt and test.bin both cases

now what code will work so that i can copy the file from my resources to "C:\Test" Folder

AND YES I RUN AS ADMIN BUT STILL ERROR ACCESS IS DENIED IN SECOND ONE ?

im noob im just beginner in vb.net so thanks alot if u cud help me :)

Comment: Having admin access doesn't allow you to change/write/remove files from everywhere. The C:\ drive is pretty often a denied path to write to unless you write to a folder in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the filename in the path. And also, you need to convert the file from resource to Bytes array. Because that's what the `WriteAllBytes()` function would be expecting

Do a search in Google.

Comment: Hi it worked After specifying file name and when put resource as test.bin but doesnot work as resource test.txt shows 1 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'.                                                                                                                                 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\AAA\Test.bin", My.Resources.Test)
    End Sub

Comment: @Js78955 - Please review the documentation for the `WriteAllBytes` method.  The second parameter to that method expects an array of bytes.  You seem to be passing it a string, which is why you get an error.  If you wish to pass a string, then you should use the `WriteAllText` method as Saeed above indicates.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem Was That You Where Writing To A Null Path Like This "C:\test" , Instead You Have To Include The Extension Of The File You Want To Write

Example If You Have A test.txt File In Your Resources Then You Use It like This

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Test.txt", My.Resources.test)
```