# Getting "Access Denied" while trying to save executable files on C drive

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to make an application that **copy/saves** an **[.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe)**(app.exe) file on program-files folder on drive C from my resources. I have tried several ways to complete the process. But my luck didn't help. I am currently using [Windows 7] Professional(Activated). Here's some ways I have tried(Included below).

- I have searched on [Google], [Yahoo] and [Bing]
- I have searched on [StachOverflow]
- I have changed `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` to `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
- I have executed the application [as administrator]
- I have started Visual Studio on administrator mode
- I have tried changing folders(On C drive)

Here's my code to copy/save the .exe (Included Below)

```
Dim path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)

Private Sub Spread(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal File As Object)
    Dim FByte() As Byte = File
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, FByte, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Spread(path, My.Resources.putty)
End Sub
```

Appreciate! Sifat, Dipta

Comment: When debugging, one of the things to do is check the parameters you are passing. Here, you are trying to write to a directory as if it were a file.

Comment: So how do you recommend me to accomplish it? By creating a sub directory and then save it? I would appreciate more if you get your self a little cleared. Thanks again.

Comment: You write data to files, not directories. You need a file name.

Comment: Thanks Raymond,
How could I write data to the file? Basically you meant to create a file and then insert data into it right? But the app.exe I am trying to save isn't created/coded by me. The app name is putty.exe. I am still struggling with this issue. You would help me more if you include some codes to get  myself plained. Thanks again for your support.

Comment: I know it's maybe getting annoying for you to attempt on helping me on a simple case. Once again, thanks and I am waiting for you reply.

Comment: So far, you don't have a file. All you have is a directory. You need to choose a name for the file, then [write to that file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247308/cant-write-file-to-hard-disk-in-vb-net)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't see any option(s) to rep you. I am kinda new. But still you helped a lot and appreciate that.